# TweepError: Twitter error response: status code = 403

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm trying to extract the amount of #btc since 2019-01-01 per day.

I know the error is about permission, but I'm already using the keys generated from Twitter developer's portal.

Here's my code, I deleted my developer keys.

```
# Python Script to Extract tweets of a
# particular Hashtag using Tweepy and Pandas


# import modules
import pandas as pd
import tweepy


# function to display data of each tweet
def printtweetdata(n, ith_tweet):
    print()
    print(f"Tweet {n}:")
    print(f"Username:{ith_tweet[0]}")
    print(f"Description:{ith_tweet[1]}")
    print(f"Location:{ith_tweet[2]}")
    print(f"Following Count:{ith_tweet[3]}")
    print(f"Follower Count:{ith_tweet[4]}")
    print(f"Total Tweets:{ith_tweet[5]}")
    print(f"Retweet Count:{ith_tweet[6]}")
    print(f"Tweet Text:{ith_tweet[7]}")
    print(f"Hashtags Used:{ith_tweet[8]}")


# function to perform data extraction
def scrape(words, date_since, numtweet):
    
    # Creating DataFrame using pandas
    db = pd.DataFrame(columns=['username', 'description', 'location', 'following',
                            'followers', 'totaltweets', 'retweetcount', 'text', 'hashtags'])
    
    # We are using .Cursor() to search through twitter for the required tweets.
    # The number of tweets can be restricted using .items(number of tweets)
    tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=words, lang="en",
                        since=date_since, tweet_mode='extended').items(numtweet)
    
    # .Cursor() returns an iterable object. Each item in
    # the iterator has various attributes that you can access to
    # get information about each tweet
    list_tweets = [tweet for tweet in tweets]
    
    # Counter to maintain Tweet Count
    i = 1
    
    # we will iterate over each tweet in the list for extracting information about each tweet
    for tweet in list_tweets:
        username = tweet.user.screen_name
        description = tweet.user.description
        location = tweet.user.location
        following = tweet.user.friends_count
        followers = tweet.user.followers_count
        totaltweets = tweet.user.statuses_count
        retweetcount = tweet.retweet_count
        hashtags = tweet.entities['hashtags']
        
        # Retweets can be distinguished by a retweeted_status attribute,
        # in case it is an invalid reference, except block will be executed
        try:
            text = tweet.retweeted_status.full_text
        except AttributeError:
            text = tweet.full_text
        hashtext = list()
        for j in range(0, len(hashtags)):
            hashtext.append(hashtags[j]['text'])
        
        # Here we are appending all the extracted information in the DataFrame
        ith_tweet = [username, description, location, following,
                    followers, totaltweets, retweetcount, text, hashtext]
        db.loc[len(db)] = ith_tweet
        
        # Function call to print tweet data on screen
        printtweetdata(i, ith_tweet)
        i = i+1
    filename = 'scraped_tweets.csv'
    
    # we will save our database as a CSV file.
    db.to_csv(filename)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    # Enter your own credentials obtained
    # from your developer account
    consumer_key = ""
    consumer_secret = ""
    access_key = ""
    access_secret = ""
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    
    # Enter Hashtag and initial date
    print("Enter Twitter HashTag to search for")
    words = input()
    print("Enter Date since The Tweets are required in yyyy-mm--dd")
    date_since = input()
    
    # number of tweets you want to extract in one run
    numtweet = 100
    scrape(words, date_since, numtweet)
    print('Scraping has completed!')
```

Here's the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TweepError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-dee0a1a7784b> in <module>()
     98         # number of tweets you want to extract in one run
     99         numtweet = 100
--> 100         scrape(words, date_since, numtweet)
    101         print('Scraping has completed!')

6 frames
<ipython-input-4-dee0a1a7784b> in scrape(words, date_since, numtweet)
     38         # the iterator has various attributes that you can access to
     39         # get information about each tweet
---> 40         list_tweets = [tweet for tweet in tweets]
     41 
     42         # Counter to maintain Tweet Count

<ipython-input-4-dee0a1a7784b> in <listcomp>(.0)
     38         # the iterator has various attributes that you can access to
     39         # get information about each tweet
---> 40         list_tweets = [tweet for tweet in tweets]
     41 
     42         # Counter to maintain Tweet Count

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tweepy/cursor.py in __next__(self)
     49 
     50     def __next__(self):
---> 51         return self.next()
     52 
     53     def next(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tweepy/cursor.py in next(self)
    241         if self.current_page is None or self.page_index == len(self.current_page) - 1:
    242             # Reached end of current page, get the next page...
--> 243             self.current_page = self.page_iterator.next()
    244             while len(self.current_page) == 0:
    245                 self.current_page = self.page_iterator.next()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tweepy/cursor.py in next(self)
    130 
    131         if self.index >= len(self.results) - 1:
--> 132             data = self.method(max_id=self.max_id, parser=RawParser(), *self.args, **self.kwargs)
    133 
    134             if hasattr(self.method, '__self__'):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tweepy/binder.py in _call(*args, **kwargs)
    251                 return method
    252             else:
--> 253                 return method.execute()
    254         finally:
    255             method.session.close()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tweepy/binder.py in execute(self)
    232                     raise RateLimitError(error_msg, resp)
    233                 else:
--> 234                     raise TweepError(error_msg, resp, api_code=api_error_code)
    235 
    236             # Parse the response payload

TweepError: Twitter error response: status code = 403
```

Comment: your code works for me (creates the file as expected). Are the keys working in a simple oauth and tweepy api call? have you managed to get a 200 response? maybe just deleting and reentering the keys into the file. perhaps you accidentally got a character in there and don't know it.

Comment: No luck, I get the consumer key and secret from here https://imgur.com/Y3zExS8 and access key and secret from here https://imgur.com/KWKmZEN. Right?

Comment: I believe so. It’s been a while since I got my keys. Maybe the app isn’t enabled correctly. Might have to retrace your steps creating that????

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue and I resolved it by going back to my Developer Portal and applying for "Elevated Access". All 403 status code errors are related to authentication issues.